# Slidify - subscript out of bounds error while converting Rmd file

Tags: r, slidify

I created a very simple index.Rmd file.  After running solidify("index.Rmd") I got the following:

> |.................................................................| 100%
>    ordinary text without R code
>    output file: index.md
>
> Copying files to libraries/frameworks/io2012... 
>     Copying files to libraries/highlighters/highlight.js... 
>     Error in x[[element]] :
>           subscript out of bounds

Totally lost about what to do next.

I tried opening the .md file in RStudio and then selecting the "preview html" button. I received this error:

```
Error in x[[element]] : subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... FUN -> get_assets -> unlist -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN
Execution halted
```

I should add to the above, that I tried opening the .md file in RStudio and then selecting the "preview html" button. I received this error:

> Error in x[[element]] : subscript out of bounds 
>   Calls:  ... FUN -> get_assets -> unlist -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN > Execution halted

EDIT: I was trying to embed a shiny application. I was able to get the presentation working fine when I abandoned that attempt and eliminated bot the embedded application and the YAML tags for shiny. I will start the process from scratch and see if I can find the root cause of the issue - but it is clearly linked to my attempt at embedding shiny.

Comment: @ZygD: Done as suggested.

Comment: Without the actual Rmd file , I don't think it's possible to guess what the problem is.

Comment: I was trying to embed a shiny application.  I was able to get the presentation working fine when I abandoned that attempt and eliminated bot the embedded application and the YAML tags for shiny.  I will start the process from scratch and see if I can find the root cause of the issue - but it is clearly linked to my attempt at embedding shiny.